# What is the highest common factor of $n$ and $2n + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to find the highest common factor of $n$ and $2n + 1$, but I am not sure how to go about it, perhaps it is clear that the $lcm(2n+1, n)$ is $n(2n+1)$ and from this we can get the $hcf$ as 1, but I am not sure if that is a good enough argument.

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint:** Euclidean division algorithm

Comment: Isn't it the same as GCD? (in which case, the answer is obviously $1$).

Comment: Why is it clear that lcm$(2n+1,n)=n(2n+1)$? This is correct, but it seems exactly as difficult as showing that hcf$(n,2n+1)=1$.

Comment: @TonyK that's why I said perhaps, I wasn't sure if one was more intuitively correct than the other, apparently not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $d=\gcd(n,2n+1)$, then d divides $n$ and $2n+1$, and so
d divides $(2n+1)-2n=1$. Therefore, $d=1$.

In particular, since $ab=\gcd(a,b)\cdot lcm(a,b)$, you have that
$$lcm(2n+1,n)=n(2n+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

In general if $m$ divides $a$ and $b,$  then $m$ divides $ax+by$ for any integers $x,y.$ Because  there are  integers $u,v$ with $a=mu$ and $b=mv,$ so $ax+by=(mu)x+(mv)y=m(ux+vy)$ is an integer-multiple of $m.$

So if $m$ divides $n$ and $2n+1,$ then $m$ divides $(n)(-2)+(2n+1)(1)=1.$

For $a,b\in \mathbb N$ we have $ab=\gcd(a,b)\cdot$ lcm$ (a,b).$ So  lcm $(a,b)=ab$ iff $\gcd (a,b)=1.$ But how would you prove that lcm$(n,2n+1)=n(2n+1)$ without assuming that $\gcd (n,2n+1)=1$?